# I need to add a Filter according to date of birth using Firebase Query

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have saved Firestore Database in the date of birth formate now I want to add a filter query according to date and month get user BirthDay. Suppose that I saved a Doctor Date of birth like 14-10-1980 now I need to filer his BirthDay tell me how to get this from Date of Birth

```
    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("d-M");
    String formattedDate = df.format(c);

    Query query = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection(TABLE_KEY_ALL_DATA).orderBy("docDob").startAt(formattedDate+"\uf8ff");
    query.addSnapshotListener((snapshot1, e1) -> {
        if (e1 != null) {
            return;
        }
        addNewDoctorModelList = snapshot1.toObjects(QualificationData.class);

        try {
            Collections.sort(addNewDoctorModelList, new Comparator<QualificationData>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(QualificationData lhs, QualificationData rhs) {
                    return lhs.getDocName().compareTo(rhs.getDocName());
                }
            });
        }
        catch ( NullPointerException e2){
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }

        reminderListAdapter = new ReminderListAdapter(addNewDoctorModelList,getActivity(), this);
        remindersRecyclerviewBinding.reminderListDoctor.setAdapter(reminderListAdapter);
    });
```

please suggest me thank you in advance I would appreciate every response

Comment: can you add firebase structure.

Comment: its simple formate as string-like 10-10-1980

Comment: I need to filter according to first date and month like 10-10

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

For filter dates using Firestore, first you need to be using the `Timestamp` type from Firestore, and then you can filter using a simple string on YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
let start = new Date('2017-01-01');

Query query = firestoreInstance.collection(TABLE_KEY_ALL_DATA).orderBy("docDob").startAt(start)
//perform query listener
```

Comment: I have done this I did not get as I needed than finally I add in a list than filter with for loop directly cant acces date and month in from  firebase only months and date